# How can I backup my data in TripIt?

Tags: backup, tripit

I have quite a lot of trip data accumulated in [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com/), the travel tracking website - various itineraries and trips across the years. In case I either decide to close my account, or TripIt becomes unavailable for some reason, I'd like to back that data up.

In an ideal world, what I'd get out of TripIt is a PDF similar to the one I get when I print out an individual trip, but for all of the trips. However, I'm curious as to what other options there are - can I get accumulated calendar data for all of my trips instead, for example?

Note that I have 100s of trips, so any manual solution on a per-trip basis will not be practical. It would be a bonus if my backup mechanism could be easily automated or run from some kind of script.

I have a TripIt Pro account, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a tool that will download all the data using, using an API key you can generate.

Note, I haven't tested it, but I'll just leave this here for the next person to stumble across:  https://github.com/muness/tripit-export-trips-to-xml

and this one:
https://github.com/FiloSottile/tripit-to-flightdiary

Comment: Thanks. I should have updated this answer before, but the first one is what I'm actually using now - or I should say, a forked version of it: https://github.com/andrewferrier/tripit-export-trips-to-xml/.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a complete answer, but one approach I have started taking is to backup the `.ics` calendar feed that TripIt provides from my account, which includes at least events with a time. Sign in to TripIt and go the [Publishing Options](https://www.tripit.com/account/edit/section/publishing_options) page, and ensure the Calendar Feed is turned on. Now hit Subscribe, and copy and paste the URL shown. Replace `webcal` with `http`, and you can then use it with an HTTP GETting tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

```
wget http://www.tripit.com/feed/ical/private/<some-random-id>/tripit.ics
```

Comment: Only works for the last 90 days of trips, unfortunately. For the rest, you have to do it totally manually per https://tripit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/226108007-Past-trips-on-your-calendar